# Passing multiple callback in Code Igniter form validation rules

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, validation

I want to pass multiple callbacks in codeigniter form validation rules.... but only one of the callbacks work

I am using this syntax in my contoller

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules(           
                array(
                    'field' => 'field_name',
                    'label' => 'Field Name',
                    'rules' => 'callback_fieldcallback_1|callback_fieldcallback_2[param]',
                    'errors' => array(
                        'fieldcallback_1' => 'Error message for rule 1.',
                        'fieldcallback_2' => 'Error message for rule 2.',
                        )
                    ),
                );
```

and the callback functions are....

```
function fieldcallback_1 (){
      if(condition == TRUE){
              return TRUE;
      } else {
              return FALSE;
      }

}

function fieldcallback_2 ($param){
      if(condition == TRUE){
              return TRUE;
      } else {
              return FALSE;
      }

}
```

Someone please help me out with this problem.... any other solutions regarding passing multiple callbacks in form validation rules are also appreciated...

Comment: Why not call validation functions inside of another callback function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All validation routines must have at least one argument which is the value of the field to be validated. So, a callback that has no extra arguments should be defined like this.

```
function fieldcallback_1($str){
      return ($str === "someValue");
}
```

A callback that requires two arguments is defined like this

```
function fieldcallback_2 ($str, $param){
    //are they the same value?
    if($str === $param){
        return TRUE;
     } else {
         $this->form_validation->set_message('fieldcallback_2', 'Error message for rule 2.');
         //Note: `set_message()` rule name (first argument) should not include the prefix "callback_"
         return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: No, $str and $param are not the same value. I am comparing whether $str > $param.

Comment: I use equality only as an example. Substitute the condition of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this?

```
     $this->form_validation->set_rules(           
            array(
                'field' => 'field_name',
                'label' => 'Field Name',
                'rules' => 'callback_fieldcallback_1[param]'),
     );

   // Functions for rules
   function fieldcallback_1 ($param){
       if(condition == TRUE){
               return fieldcallback_2($param);
       } else {
                $this->form_validation->set_message('callback_fieldcallback_1', 'Error message for rule 1.');

               return FALSE;
       }

 }

 function fieldcallback_2 ($param){
       if(condition == TRUE){
               return TRUE;
       } else {
                $this->form_validation->set_message('callback_fieldcallback_1', 'Error message for rule 2.');
               return FALSE;
       }

 }
```